# Magento 2: change the order of the product page blocks

Tags: magento-2.1, product, page-layouts

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

On the **product page**, I need to change the layout so that the product *photo* stays at the left side of the page and the product *info* at the right, with *both div's floated left*.

The `catalog_product_view.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="main" before="product.info.media"/>
</page>
```

brings the photo before the main info but also brings the tabs *between* them:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="product media"></div>
  <!-- Tabs BEGIN -->
  <div>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"></ul>
   <div class="tab-content"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Tabs END -->
  <div class="product-info-main"></div>
</div>
```

What I need is:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="product media"></div>
  <div class="product-info-main"></div>
  <div>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"></ul>
   <div class="tab-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How must I change the code above and/or what other files shall I edit to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by changing `catalog_product_view.xml`, to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="main" before="product.info.media"/>
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="content" before="product.info.details"/>
    <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in before **body** end in `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
 <move element="product.info.media" destination="content" before="product.info.main"/>
```

I have tested this its working !!